# Internal Server Error Xcode Continuous Integration

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I've successfully created a Bot and run an integration test for an iOS application hosted on a remote SVN server over HTTP. When trying to run the same test over HTTPS the test fails and I receive the error: **Integration failed. Unexpected internal server error. See the integration's logs for more details.** The certificate used for the SVN server is self signed and I ensured I am able to still update/commit to the server over HTTPS. After looking through the logs I can't seem to find out what the error is or how to fix it. (I would post the logs but it's like 100 pages to read through...)

Steps taken so far:

- Deleted the bot and project, checked out the project over HTTPS, re-made the bot.
- Ensure the correct HTTPS repository is listed both in OS X Server --> Xcode --> Repositories, and in Xcode's repository preferences. (Deleted the old repository as well)
- Place the self signed certificate into the keychain's **System Store** and ensure it is set to Trust All.
- Modified the Xcode config file **xcsbuildd.plist** and changed TrustSelfSignedSSLCertificates to true.

Nothing has seemed to fix it so far. If anyone can think of a fix for this issue please let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem - OS X Server fails to do a checkout from an SVN repository. However, both XCode 4 and 5 are able to do it with the exact same settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to fix this by adding to the `System` keychain our company's `Root certificate authority` and `Intermediate certificate authority` certs.

I used Charles (web debugging proxy) to intercept requests and responses and see what was wrong. It gave me a clue that OS X Server was struggling with certs.